# Merging Two Files with Difference only

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, join

I have two files. `file1` contains text as follows:

```
#This Data written by the platform Team
id=kingDB
```

`file2` contains the text as follows:

```
#This Data written by the platform Team
id=kiteDB,mangoDB
```

I want to merge the `file1` data in `file2`,
Afterwards **`file2`** needs to be as follows:

```
#This Data written by the platform Team
id=kiteDB,mangoDB,kingDB
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Is it always one line? Are there only comments at the top of the files (or between lines if there are multiple). If multiple lines, are the 'id=' parts unique?

Comment: there is only two lines in each files,first line will be same comment and second have id common,only id= .. text will be different,so from file1 need to add id Text if differ from file2 by separating comma.

Answer (score 3):

Usual way to merge to files is `join`

```
join -t = file{1,2} | sed s/=/,/2
```

Comment: thanks all, I have tried with Anthon solutions its working fine

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sed`, `tail` and `cut`:

```
 sed -i "s/=\(.*\)/=\1,$(tail -1 file1 | cut -d = -f 2)/" file2
```

The commands between `$(...)` first take the last line of `file1`, cuts it based on the `=` character and takes the seconds field (`kingDB`), then it puts that at the end of the line with '=' of the second file.¹

Not all `sed` versions have `-i`, if yours doesn't try:

```
sed "s/=\(.*\)/=\1,$(tail -1 file1 | cut -d = -f 2)/" file2 > file2.tmp
mv -f file2.tmp file2
```

¹ <sub>I am assuming here that `file2` did end in a newline, if not you can do without `sed`</sub>

Answer (score 0):

If you have single line you can use the following code:

```
echo "id=" $(paste -d "" <( awk -F',' {'printf "%s,%s,", $1, $2  '} file2 ) <( awk -F'=' {'print $2'} file1 ) <(sed -i 's/id=//g' file2 )) > file2
```